# Android Firebase Libraries, Instrumented Test - No static method registerDefaultInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, dependencies

Trying to run instrumented tests in Android Studio results in a

```
Test running failed: Process crashed.
```

In greater detail in the logcat

```
E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nikolam.colorme.debug, PID: 19841
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method registerDefaultInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite;)V in class Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite' appears in /data/app/com.nikolam.colorme.debug.test-lZqsu6pVWp2DVtFzU1uYgg==/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.v1.ApplicationInfo.<clinit>(ApplicationInfo.java:1085)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.v1.ApplicationInfo.newBuilder(ApplicationInfo.java:533)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.transport.TransportManager.<init>(TransportManager.java:139)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.transport.TransportManager.<clinit>(TransportManager.java:91)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.transport.TransportManager.getInstance(TransportManager.java:149)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.AppStateMonitor.getInstance(AppStateMonitor.java:64)
        at com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider.attachInfo(FirebasePerfProvider.java:65)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

The closest thing I found was [this issue on github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1907) but I tried multiple setups of excluding the protobuf java from my dependancies. I tried to exclude it from all projects, just from the app module, from all  modules except the app module and so on. I use Firebase performance in multiple modules.

I tried finding the `protobuf-java` and here is where I found it

```
lintClassPath - The lint embedded classpath
\--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:27.1.0
     +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:27.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:27.1.0
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:27.1.0
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.8.1
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.2
     |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.3
     |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.18
     |    |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72
     |    |    |    |         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72
     |    |    |    |         |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.72
     |    |    |    |         |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     |    |    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72
     |    |    |    |              \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:27.1.0
     |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:dvlib:27.1.0
     |    |    |    \--- com.android.tools:common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:repository:27.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0
     |    |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12
     |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1
     |    |    |    |    +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1
     |    |    |    |    |    \--- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0
     |    |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.1
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:3.0.7
     |    |    |    |    +--- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:1.8
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:1.2.15
     |    |    |    |    \--- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1
     |    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 28.1-jre (*)
     |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5
     |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12
     |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6
     |    |    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6
     |    |    |         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10
     |    |    |         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
     |    |    |         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
     |    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:4.1.0
     |    |    \--- com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:27.1.0
     |    |         +--- com.android.tools:common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |         +--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
     |    |         \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:4.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:27.1.0
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.1.0
     |    |    |    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:27.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56
     |    |    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0  -- HERE 
     |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824
     |    \--- com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:4.1.0-alpha01-6193524
     |         \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0 -- HERE 
     +--- com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:4.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:4.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools:common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5
     |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     |    |    \--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android:zipflinger:4.1.0
     |    |    \--- com.android.tools:common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android:signflinger:4.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:apksig:4.1.0
     |    |    \--- com.android:zipflinger:4.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:annotations:27.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre (*)
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:apksig:4.1.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:4.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9 -> 3.0.2
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:23.0 -> 28.1-jre (*)
     |    |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56 (*)
     |    |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
     |    |    \--- com.android.tools.build:apksig:4.1.0
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     |    +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56 (*)
     |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0
     |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0
     |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0
     |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0
     |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0 (*)
     |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0
     |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0
     |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0 (*)
     |    +--- it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0
     |    +--- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9
     |    \--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1
     +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:4.1.0 (*)
     +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:27.1.0
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824
     +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:27.1.0
     +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:27.1.0
     +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.1.0 (*)
     +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint:27.1.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:27.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:27.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:27.1.0
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:4.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     |    |    |    |    \--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:27.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:27.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0
     |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- com.android.tools.build:builder-model:4.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:27.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:27.1.0
     |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:27.1.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:27.1.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72 (*)
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.0
     |    +--- com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:27.1.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.1.0
     |    |    +--- com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:4.1.0 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre (*)
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre (*)
     +--- com.android:zipflinger:4.1.0 (*)
     +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72 (*)
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72 (*)
```

Other Firebase libraries depend on

```
com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0
```

The whole dependencies.log is large so I dont know how to post it

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, but only on Pixel device. On Samsung device it works fine

Answer (score 20):

In my case it seems to be caused by `protobuf-lite:3.0.1` dependency from recently updated `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'` which I was able to fix with this exclude

```
androidTestImplementation (androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'){
    exclude module: "protobuf-lite"
}
```

and it's working for my needs (I use this library only for DrawerActions), however it is not very elegant solution.

Given the date of your post it's probably caused by something else (since the mentioned library was updated few days ago), unless you were using some alpha version.

I recommend to check recently updated dependencies in your gradle file. You can also compare differences in output of `./gradlew :app:dependencies | grep protobuf` before and after that dependency change and then examine the full dependency tree for the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Completing @Almighty's answer when using ktx:

```
api/implementation/testImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0') {
        exclude(module = "protobuf-lite")
    }
```