# Espresso tests not running in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-espresso

I'm making some espresso tests for my application in android studio , it was working and suddently stopped working , basically the test builds and starts but it gets stuck in test results and show nothings , i mean it shows no tests passing . if someone could help i will appreciate it , Thank you

- This is a screenshot from my android studio ( it shows launch succeded but tests dont start)

[image]

Comment: Did you try restarting AS?

Comment: Yes i did try to clean  , rebuild and make project as well as reinstallig android studio , but sounds like it kepts old config so i don't really know what happened .

Comment: Weird i found that issue is with espress-contrib library , when i comment and resync , tests start ..

Comment: can you share the build.gradle file ?

Comment: @PradapPandian I have already fixed the issue , when using the latest version of espesso-contrib dependency , it causes that issue , so i had to downgrade the version and it worked

Comment: glad you got the solution

Comment: Maybe fix from this answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67295843/android-firebase-libraries-instrumented-test-no-static-method-registerdefault) can help you

Comment: @Taki did you updated espresso-contrib recently? Are you using a newer version than 3.3.0 now? I'm still facing the problem and I'm not able to update any further then 3.3.0 (3.4.0 and 3.5.0 aren't working). Did you solved it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74449061/espresso-contrib-3-3-0-works-fine-but-any-newer-version-results-in-build-failure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downgrading helped me:

`androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0` -> 3.3.0

`androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0` -> 3.3.0

Comment: For me, downgrading to 3.2.0 worked. 3.3.0 didn't work.

Comment: Do you know what causes the problem? Or have any clue? Still facing the same problem with the newest version of espresso-contrib (3.5.0)

Comment: I have found this question more close to the issue i am facing "Tests Cancelled, 0 passed"
but downgrading espresso-core and espresso-contrib did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Same thing with Kaspresso 1.4.0, downgrading to 1.3.0 helps